# client.guilds.cache.get(...). members.get It is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm doing a command with cargo, this error comes and I can't understand it, here's the script:

```
const member = client.guilds.cache.get('980553630480474232').members.get(interaction.user.id);
```

And here is the error:
`client.guilds.cache.get(...).members.get is not a function.`

Comment: You are calling a value (probably `undefined`) which is not a function. Isn't this clear enough?

Comment: but I don't know what value it is, and when I put ```interaction.author.id``` it gets the error cannot reading "id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v13, you need to use `.cache.get()`, if the error persists double check your guild ID.

If you encounter such an error try `console.log()` to see wich value is undefined, because such errors results from having undefined values.

And for future advice if you need a value more than once in your code define it first, in this case use

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('980553630480474232');
const member = guild.members.cache.get('ID')
```

Side Note: If this is a command file, you can directly get the guild using:

```js
interaction.guild.members.get(interaction.user.id)
```